# Is it possible to hand solder a component with a peak temp of 250 C?

Tags: soldering, solder-paste

I'm trying to mount an [RF module that has 33 edge castellation pins](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/286/MeshConnect_EM357_Mini_Modules_DS-55615.pdf).  The data sheet says that the peak temperature is 250°C.  I'm using 60/40 lead solder for a lower melting point but the solder will only melt at 315°C and I suspect that I'm burning the gates on these expensive modules.

Is reflow soldering the only way to mount components like these?

Comment: I would recommend posting a link to the actual RF module, if possible. Regardless, I believe you are mistaking the 315C

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder#Lead_solder) `Alloys commonly used for electrical soldering are 60/40 Tin/lead (Sn/Pb) which melts at 370 °F or 188 °C`

Comment: I'm using the Hakko FX-888D with the 60/40 tin/lead.  I'm quite sure the programming is in Fahrenheit and when I place the tinned tip up to the solder, it will only melt if I the programmable temp says 600F(315C).  Could it be my tip?

Comment: http://www.cel.com/pdf/datasheets/MeshConnect_EM357_Mini_Modules_DS.pdf

Comment: The link doesn't work. Here is an [alternative link](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/286/MeshConnect_EM357_Mini_Modules_DS-55615.pdf)

Comment: Well, the big problem, as Kaz said, is that the tip temp is not going to be equal to the melting temp when you first touch the solder. I like to solder stuff with my tip at 800F. Better irons will self adjust and keep a steady temperature more reliably.

Comment: @scld I think the problem that I'm having has to do with calibration but I'm not sure how to calibrate.  If I set my tip at 800F, my solder will melt fine but is it going to fry the pin on the RF module?

Comment: Intermittent high temperature shouldn't do damage. The problem actually lies, sometimes, in a relatively COOL soldering tip where you need to get most of the board up to high temperature before the flow happens. I would recommend a higher temperature for a short duration. Then, in between soldering each pin, let the board cool. Or, solder a pin on the other side so the local hot spots are further apart. And, if you need to leave your iron on there for too long, pull it off and let it cool while you adjust technique/settings.

Answer (score 3):

60/40 solder melts at [somewhere around 180 to 190 degrees Celsius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solder#Lead_solder), not 300-something.

Use a temperature-controlled soldering station.

In any case, the temperature in the device itself is not necessarily as high as it is at the joint being soldered. If you work quickly, you can create a fast, local temperature rise at the joint.

Also, depending on the size and geometry of the part being soldered, sometimes it is feasible to introduce a sink which removes heat somewhere along the pin between the joint and the part itself.

Comment: Maybe he got confused with Fahrenheit? But that is only 157C, so equally, maybe not...

Comment: @gbmhunter I remember having seen the same confusion months ago in another question. Someone also had the idea that Sn/Pb melted at 300-something C but the figure did not exactly correspond to the correct F either.